# How to join with global temp table created in a previous openquery in the next openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a bit of catch-22 situation here. I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2019.

The first portion of the procedure executes a query on a linked server and writes its output in a global temp table `##TEMP1` that is created on the server executing the stored procedure.

```
SET @SQLQuery1 = 'SELECT * INTO ##TEMP1 FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ',''
        SELECT 
            COL1,
            ..........

        FROM TABLE1'')';

EXEC(@SQLQuery1);

SET @SQLQuery2 = 'SELECT * INTO ##TEMP2 FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ',''
SELECT  COL11,COL22
        .....

        FROM ##TEMP1
        INNER JOIN TABLE2
          ON (........)
'')';
```

Now I have another query that needs to run on the linked server but this query also needs to JOIN with ##TEMP1 table. But this table is getting created on the current server (not the linked server)

I get this error:

> Invalid object name '##TEMP1'

Would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

Comment: A temporary table (global or not) only persists for the duration of the scope it is created in. In the above, that would be the duration of the dynamic statement. You need to create the temporary table outside of the dynamic statement if you want to reference it outside of the dynamic statement, or in later (dynamic) statements.

Comment: Side note `'... OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + '...'` is wide open to injection. Properly quote your dynamic server name with `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: So basically I have to do CREATE TABLE ##TEMP1 ... first ?

Comment: You would need to do it **outside** of your dynamic statements, and as you want to then `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT...FROM` it, the yes it would need to be first.

Comment: Does not seem to work. Tried inserting into ##TEMP1 as  INSERT INTO ##TEMP1 EXEC(@SQLQuery1)...but when I do INSERT INTO ##TEMP2 EXEC(@SQLQuery2) I still get Invalid Object ##TEMP1 error

Comment: I can't repro the problem when you create the table outside of the dynamic statements:[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1859dbb2818419a745cb736fc16528c1)

Comment: I am using OpenQuery... so I am referenceing ##TEMP1 inside an OpenQuery statement...maybe that's what the problem is. So maybe the linked server is unable to see ##TEMP1 global temp table

Comment: You can't reference an object created on the local instance inside `OPENQUERY` which references the remote instance, no. That isn't what you show you are doing in the above question though sunny. This suggests you aren't giving the full picture. Post the full query in your question. If, however, you do want to reference the temporary object with `OPENQUERY` you'll need to change your approach and use 4 part naming instead.

Comment: Hi Larnu..imho I think I have mentioned what I need to here to give a complete picture of the problem. The actual query is very long and has lots of info I cannot share. Based on your earlier comments I think the problem is to not be able to use local global/non-global temp tables in a subsequent OpenQuery statement that is to be executed on a linked server. Maybe there is no way to do it. And I have tried the 4 naming  [localserver].[tempdb].[dbo].[##TEMP1] in the FROM part of @SQLQuery2 of the subsequent OpenQuery..but the error stays the same.

Comment: `OPENQUERY` is run on the remote server. Of course you cannot access a table created on the local instance on a remote instance; it's on the local instance. `CREATE TABLE #MyTable (ID int); SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,N'SELECT * FROM #yTable');` will never work as the table `#MyTable` wasn't create on `LinkedServer`; it has no context there.

Comment: Yeah... I figured..I will need to refactor my queries so that all the Linked Server queries are executed on the remote server and then results stored on the local temp. Logically also it does not make sense to execute query1 on remote linked server, then store results in local #temp, and then execute (query2+results in local #temp) again on remote linked server, when (query1 + query2) can be run on remote linked in the first place. What I was not clear was global temp. Seems that is global for all sessions on the local server. It is still NOT visible to the remote linked server.

Comment: *"It is still NOT visible to the remote linked server."* not a local object is still local. If I create a global temporary table, and it was available to every SQL Server connected to the network/internet that would be a huge concern for many reasons.